# Enum object could not converted to string

Tags: php, symfony

I try this [guide](https://www.strangebuzz.com/en/blog/using-php-8-1-enumerations-in-a-symfony-project) to use enum in my Entity. I can persist data to database. But there is error in this line

```
'booking_fees' => $bookingFeeRepository->findAll(),
```

The error says `Object of class App\Enum\BookingFeeStatusEnum could not be converted to string`.

Enum

```
<?php

namespace App\Enum;

enum BookingFeeStatusEnum: string
{
    case Hold = 'HOLD';
    case Deal = 'DEAL';
}
```

Entity

```
...

class BookingFee
{
    
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', nullable: false, enumType: BookingFeeStatusEnum::class)]
    private BookingFeeStatusEnum $status = BookingFeeStatusEnum::Hold;


...
```

Controller

```
    #[Route('', name: 'app_booking_fee_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(BookingFeeRepository $bookingFeeRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('booking_fee/index.html.twig', [
            'booking_fees' => $bookingFeeRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }
```

Form

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\BookingFee;
use App\Enum\BookingFeeStatusEnum;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EnumType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class BookingFeeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('status', EnumType::class, [
                'class' => BookingFeeStatusEnum::class
            ])
            ->add('note')
            ->add('fee')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => BookingFee::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

If I change the getter to

```
public function getStatus(): string
{
    return $this->status->value;
}

public function setStatus(BookingFeeStatusEnum $status): self
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}
```

Then there is no error. I'm not sure if in this case, returning string in getter is considered correct practice. Or is there something I missed because I read that doctrine should support Enum? Or should I just use string on entity and the data transformer on the form?

Comment: Not sure how you can get an error about the enum right at `'booking_fees' => $bookingFeeRepository->findAll(),`, you don't use it there. Can you double-check that's the actual line, and not part of the stack trace?

Comment: Ah you're right. I use it in twig. Previously it was `{{ booking_fee.status }}`, should be `{{ booking_fee.status.value }}`.

Answer (score -2):

just wondering why you did it like this:
...

```
class BookingFee
{
    
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', nullable: false, enumType: BookingFeeStatusEnum::class)]
    private BookingFeeStatusEnum $status = BookingFeeStatusEnum::Hold;


...
```

and not like this for example :

...

```
class BookingFee
{
    
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', nullable: false)]
    private string $status = BookingFeeStatusEnum::Hold->value;


...
```

i'm missing something?

Comment: The guide uses an enum class as an example, so I tried to follow it at first. I was going to use string as a fallback in case the guide is not working. I am keen to use an enum to make sure the possible values are limited, in case the entity is created from other places, like the API endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, i didn't know we could use enum like this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).